# How to keep the entire website aligned to the top when zooming-out using CSS (Firefox)?

Tags: css, firefox, zooming, viewport

I have used CSS zoom property at around 95% to zoom-out of the website (for responsive purposes).

```
html, body {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95); 
  zoom: 0.95;
  zoom: 95%; 
}
```

However, when I use the -moz-transform property for Firefox, the website aligns to the middle so there's a huge gap on top, the more zoomed-out the website gets.

When I do a manual zooming-out using `cmd + 'scroll down'` on the browser, it zooms out and the website is still aligned to the top.

**This is what happens:**

[image]

**This is what I'd like to happen:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer which is actually dead-simple.

Just need to add this to the body / html css:

```
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
```

In case someone may find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
html {
  height:900px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:900px;
  width:100%;
  background: #A2D0D0;
}


#website-container {
  width:950px;
  height:400px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background: #77A7F9;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="website-container">
Main Website
</div>
</body>
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/gez2ozj5/